# Linear combination issue

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have 4 vectors:

$u_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
         1  \\
         1  \\
         1  \\
         \end{pmatrix} $, $\; u_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
         1  \\
         1  \\
         0  \\
         \end{pmatrix} $, $\; u_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
         1  \\
         1  \\
         0  \\
         \end{pmatrix} $, $\; u_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
         0  \\
         1  \\
         0  \\
         \end{pmatrix} $

and I wanna express the following vector in terms of them:

$\; v = \begin{pmatrix}
         2  \\
         3  \\
         4  \\
         \end{pmatrix} $

I'm working this way:

First put vectors in a matrix and then put in rref:

$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1&1&1&0&2\\
      1&1&1&1&3\\
      1&0&0&0&4
    \end{array}
\right] $   => $ \left[
    \begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1&1&1&0&2\\
      0&0&0&1&1\\
      0&-1&-1&0&2
    \end{array}
\right] $ => $ \left[
    \begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1&1&1&0&2\\
      0&-1&-1&0&2\\
      0&0&0&1&1
    \end{array}
\right] $ =>

$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1&1&1&0&2\\
      0&1&1&0&-2\\
      0&0&0&1&1
    \end{array}
\right] $ => $ \left[
    \begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1&1&1&0&2\\
      0&1&1&0&-2\\
      0&0&0&1&1
    \end{array}
\right] $ => $ \left[
    \begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1&0&0&0&4\\
      0&1&1&0&-2\\
      0&0&0&1&1
    \end{array}
\right] $

but this result (4 -2 1) is meaningless to me (because $4u_1 -2u_2 + u_3 \ne v$)... does it make any sense? Can it represent some sort of coeficients of the linear combination?

If I swap $u_3$ for $u_4$ in the matrix, the (4 -2 1) is the same but it DOES make sense, because $4u_1 -2u_2 + u_4 = v$

How can I write v as combination of u's ? If I did the right way, how does this make sense?

Comment: Are $u_2$ and $u_3$ supposed to be identical?

Comment: yes, just for purpose of testing, and anyway i think this shouldnt matter, once I have enough vectors to write v as combination of u's

Comment: @Daniel Check your RREF. That $-2$ in the last column does NOT signify that you have -2 $u2$'s

Answer (score 2):

If I rewrite your augmented matrix as follows:

$\begin{bmatrix}
      1&0&0&0&\\
      0&1&1&0&\\
      0&0&0&1&\\
    \end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}
      a_1\\
      a_2\\
      a_3\\
      a_4\\
    \end{bmatrix}$
$= \begin{bmatrix}
      4\\
      -2\\
      1\\
 \end{bmatrix}$

Where $a_1, \cdots a_4$ are the coefficients of $u_1,\cdots u_4$

$\begin{bmatrix}
      a_1\\
      a_2+a_3\\
      a_4\\
\end{bmatrix}$
$= \begin{bmatrix}
      4\\
      -2\\
      1\\
 \end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(4,-2,1)$ by itself **cannot** be the right answer since you need four coefficients to give a linear combination of your four vectors.

Since your reduced matrix has a non-leading (non-pivot) column, the system will have infinitely many solutions.  You could take the third coefficient to be zero, giving the solution $(4,-2,0,1)$ which is correct since
$$4u_1-2u_2+0u_3+u_4=v\ .$$
Or you could take the second to be zero giving $(4,0,-2,1)$, which is also correct since
$$4u_1+0u_2-2u_3+u_4=v\ .$$
The general solution of your system is
$$(4,-2-\alpha,\alpha,1)$$
where $\alpha$ is a scalar, and this is also correct for any $\alpha$ since
$$4u_1+(-2-\alpha)u_2+\alpha u_3+u_4=v\ .$$
Hope this helps!

Comment: how can i find v in terms of u's? Is that method wrong?

Comment: No it's fine, but I think you are misinterpreting the final reduced matrix.  Remember that the matrix represents a system of linear equations, and you don't have any answer to your problem until you have solved the system.

Answer (score 0):

You need three linearly independent vectors to form a basis for three dimensions.

As $u_2$ and $u_3$ are in fact identical and the same, the redundant and duplicated one is unnecessary and also not needed.

Reapply your process with only three column vectors: $u_1, u_2, u_4$, and $v$.

Comment: no, i dont need three. for example, i can write (1,1,0) as combination of (1,0,0) and (0,1,0) only..

Comment: @Daniel you don't need three to write *some* examples.  However to be able to write **any** example, you will need three.  Read the sentence again, "you need three *linearly independent* vectors **to form a basis** for three dimensions."  As it so happens, $(1,1,0)=1(1,0,0) + 1(0,1,0) + 0(0,0,1)$ happens to use a zero multiple of the third standard basis element.  The point is that without needing to change those three, we could *also* express $(0,1,1)$ or $(5,2,-1)$ or $(\pi,e,-\pi)$ or any other as well.  Sometimes zeroes will be used, that's fine and expected.